# Controlling Dynamic Text in Swift application

Tags: swift, accessibility, dynamic-text

I was wondering what else can we control using **Dynamic Text** in iOS devices other than `UILabels`?

Is there a way to adjust `UIImageViews` as well for instance? Or any other `UIViews` ?

Comment: yes you can, for UIImageView, don't set width and height, only position, for UIView play with content hugging priority

Comment: and how to link them with the size picked in Dynamic Text?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a cell in your UITableViewCell, use automatic dimension, for example:

**self.yourtableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.yourtableview.estimatedRowHeight = X**

This way your uilabel can be dynamic, your UIView will also be dynamic, in a UIImageView, auto-layout with aspect ratio to fit the cell's height/width.